# How to substitute the "0" with "i" in the below line inside for loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to substitute the "0" with "i" in the below line inside for loop in javascript?

Code:

```
for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    e.form.NameLists_0__IsDeleted.checked = false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    e.form["NameLists_" + i + "__IsDeleted"].checked = false;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
e.form["NameLists_" + i + "__IsDeleted"].checked = false;
```

In javascript, you can access members using both the `member.name` syntax and `member["name"]`. They're functionally identical, the latter letting you access arbitrary names where you don't know what it is ahead of time.

Answer (score 2):

you can try like this

```
for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    e.form["NameLists_" + i + "__IsDeleted"].checked = false;
}
```